# Writing a query which creates new column for every user (userID) based on number of monitors (monitorID)

Tags: mysql, correlated-subquery

I am new to SQL. I am trying to write a query which creates new column for every user (userID) based on number of monitors (monitorID).

My intention is to use common table expression (CTE) for counting the number of monitors and then subquery for creating a new column based on monitors count.

**QUERY**

```
WITH monitors_count AS (
SELECT userID, count(monitorID) as monitors_count,
FROM monitors
GROUP BY userID
)
 
SELECT
    userID,
    (SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN monitors_count.monitors_count > 100 THEN "> 100"
            ELSE "<100"
    END;
    FROM monitors AS inside_monitors
    WHERE inside_monitors.userID = outside_monitors.userID
    )
 
FROM monitors AS outside_monitors
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH monitors_count AS (
    SELECT userID, count(monitorID) as monitors_count
    FROM monitors
    GROUP BY userID
    )
     
    SELECT
        monitors.UserID,
        CASE 
        WHEN monitors_count.monitors_count > 100 THEN "> 100"
        ELSE "<100" end as monitor_count
    FROM monitors inner join monitors_count
    On monitors.UserID= monitors_count.UserID
    Group By monitors.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks for advice. 

I removed it, and recieved this error:
`1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 13, Time: 0.194000s`

so I deleted also ; at line 13 and then received this error:

`1054 - Unknown column 'monitors_count.monitors_count' in 'field list', Time: 0.184000s`

Comment: can you try now?

Comment: thanks yusuf, I tried it and it finaly works. I needed to delete WHEREclause and replace the userID with the monitors.userID

...I have to think once more time about the joining so I understand it completely. Can you recommend some source please?

...and can you also advice how should I rewrite the question since it was closed because it was marked as "typo or a problem that can no longer be reproduced."

Thanks again!

Comment: I editted your question again, maybe they accept it

Comment: could you also edit your answer please, so I can mark it as solution? many thanks again :)

Comment: I eddited, I think now it is very simple to apply.

Comment: Yes, now it is very simple to apply. However I still see there redundant "WHERE" clause.

Comment: I think now it is OK

Comment: Now it's great and it works! Thanks a lot once more time :)